# ¿Como remplazar ultima palabra y la ultima antes de "y" de una frase en javascript?

Tags: javascript

tengo una frase que es "el coche azul y la casa verde" y tengo que cambiar la palabra azul por "rojo" y la palabra verde por "amarillo"
Basicamente, el codigo tiene que detectar la ultima palabra de toda una frase y la ultima antes de "y"
tengo un código pero solo detecta la ultima y obviamente el código tiene que funcionar el cualquier longitud de frase.

```
phrase="el coche azul y la casa verde"//solo es un ejemplo
casa="amarillo"
coche="rojo"
const frase=phrase.split(' ');
const ultima=frase[frase.length-1]; //me obtiene la ultima de la frase
const remplazar= phrase.replace(ultima, casa);
```

Answer (score 2):

Creo que te puede ser útil la función `lastIndexOf` la cual te devuelve el último índice que coincida con la búsqueda.

El siguiente código te puede dar una idea.
Se asume que siempre va a haber dos palabras que cumplan las condiciones que estableciste, de lo contrario, solo es incluir un par de revisiones.

```js
let phrase = 'el coche azul y la casa verde';
// Separar el string por espacios en un arreglo
let words = phrase.split(' ');
// Tomar la palabra antes del último "y" y cambiarlo por rojo
words[words.lastIndexOf('y') - 1] = 'rojo';
// Tomar la última palabra y cambiarla por amarilla
words[words.length - 1] = 'amarilla';

// Juntar nuevamente la frase en un string
phrase = words.join(' ');

console.log(phrase);
```

Comment: Buena respuesta. Podrías usar [Array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) para volver a unir las palabras en lugar de `Array.reduce()`.

Comment: @Triby, si me parece mejor, gracias por la sugerencia.